# Using KeycloakOIDCFilter with Spark UI - cannot configure

Tags: java, apache-spark, keycloak, openid-connect, servlet-filters

We are attempting to use [`KeycloakOIDCFilter`](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_servlet_filter_adapter) as our Apache Spark UI filter. However, we are struggling to configure the `KeycloakOIDCFilter` itself.

We have, in spark-defaults.conf:

```
spark.ui.filters=org.keycloak.adapters.servlet.KeycloakOIDCFilter
```

This is picked up successfully, and the Spark master logs show this filter being applied to all URL routes.

We have generated a client config file in the Keycloak Admin Console, which has spit out a `keycloak-oidc.json`.

**But how do we tell `KeycloakOIDCFilter` about this information**?

From the Spark [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

> Filter parameters can also be specified in the configuration,
> by setting config entries of the form `spark.<class name of filter>.param.<param name>=<value>`
> For example:
>
> ```
> spark.ui.filters=com.test.filter1
> spark.com.test.filter1.param.name1=foo
> spark.com.test.filter1.param.name2=bar
> ```

In our case that would seem to be:

```
spark.org.keycloak.adapters.servlet.KeycloakOIDCFilter.param.<name>=<value>
```

However, the [KeycloakOIDCFilter](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/adapters/oidc/servlet-filter/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/servlet/KeycloakOIDCFilter.java) Java class has only two constructors. One takes no parameters at all and one takes a `KeycloakConfigResolver`.

The Keycloak [Java servlet filter adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_servlet_filter_adapter) docs only talk about `web.xml` which isn't applicable in the case of configuring Spark.

**So how can we properly configure/point to parameters for the `KeycloakOIDCFilter` servlet filter?**

---

Update: We've determined that `spark.org.keycloak.adapters.servlet.KeycloakOIDCFilter.param.keycloak.config.file` can be used to point to a config file, but it appears that [Spark does not use SessionManager](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-38693?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel), leading to a separate error that may or may not be resolvable.

Comment: Since Spark-UI uses Jetty, maybe a Jetty Adapter would help?  https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_jetty9_adapter

Comment: @Matruskan sounds interesting but I am far from a Java person. Could you briefly describe how that would be done? Through Spark config and/or adding to Spark's JARs directory?

Comment: I'm also not familiar with Spark, sorry :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested the solution but, according to the Keycloak and Spark documentation you cited, and the source code of [KeycloakOIDCFilter](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/bfce612641a70e106b20b136431f0e4046b5c37f/adapters/oidc/servlet-filter/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/servlet/KeycloakOIDCFilter.java), assuming you are using a file in your filesystem, the following configuration could work:

```
spark.ui.filters=org.keycloak.adapters.servlet.KeycloakOIDCFilter
spark.org.keycloak.adapters.servlet.KeycloakOIDCFilter.param.keycloak.config.file=/path/to/keycloak-oidc.json
```

Or this other one if your config is accesible as a web app resource, through `getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(...)`, instead of a file:

```
spark.ui.filters=org.keycloak.adapters.servlet.KeycloakOIDCFilter
spark.org.keycloak.adapters.servlet.KeycloakOIDCFilter.param.keycloak.config.path=/WEB-INF/keycloak-oidc.json
```

Please, note that they indicate that filters parameters can also be specified in the configuration: afaik, it doesn't mean that the filter should have any special constructor or something similar.

This configuration is performed by the [`addFilters`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a127d912927f17b7754b89f4e315a5e3fb6461d4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/JettyUtils.scala#L533-L551):

```scala
/**
  * Add filters, if any, to the given ServletContextHandlers. Always adds a filter at the end
  * of the chain to perform security-related functions.
  */
private def addFilters(handler: ServletContextHandler, securityMgr: SecurityManager): Unit = {
  conf.get(UI_FILTERS).foreach { filter =>
    logInfo(s"Adding filter to ${handler.getContextPath()}: $filter")
    val oldParams = conf.getOption(s"spark.$filter.params").toSeq
      .flatMap(Utils.stringToSeq)
      .flatMap { param =>
        val parts = param.split("=")
        if (parts.length == 2) Some(parts(0) -> parts(1)) else None
      }
      .toMap


    val newParams = conf.getAllWithPrefix(s"spark.$filter.param.").toMap


    JettyUtils.addFilter(handler, filter, oldParams ++ newParams)
}
```

and [addFilter](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a127d912927f17b7754b89f4e315a5e3fb6461d4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/JettyUtils.scala#L429-L437):

```scala
def addFilter(
      handler: ServletContextHandler,
      filter: String,
      params: Map[String, String]): Unit = {
    val holder = new FilterHolder()
    holder.setClassName(filter)
    params.foreach { case (k, v) => holder.setInitParameter(k, v) }
    handler.addFilter(holder, "/*", EnumSet.allOf(classOf[DispatcherType]))
}
```

methods in the [`JettyUtils`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a127d912927f17b7754b89f4e315a5e3fb6461d4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/JettyUtils.scala) class in the source code of Spark UI.

Comment: Good find on `addFilters()`. `param.keycloak.config.file` _does_ seem to be recognized, however, we've discovered that [Spark does not use SessionManager](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-38693?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel), which leads to a new error. I realize I neglected to update my question with that info though, so I will mark your answer as accepted if no others come along.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback @BradSolomon. I am sorry that a new error has appeared. Please feel free to edit the question if you need to, the important thing is that you manage to solve the problem.